# Update Windows 10 Update Status Times In Security Settings

Tags: windows-update, windows-registry, automatic-updates

We use an RMM Software that controls and manages Microsoft Patches.
It is not able to automatically update the 'Last Checked Time' in the Update and Security Module.

In previous windows we would automatically update the below regkeys with the current Date/Time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).
It appears these Regkeys are no longer available in Windows 10.

Does anyone know where the date and time is being pulled from and is it editable?

Windows 8.1 and below

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Detect\LastSuccessTime

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Download\LastSuccessTime

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install\LastSuccessTime